# How to users login in twitter account in my website

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am starting a site and I want to know is their any modules or widgets already out before learning how to code it into my site that would let a user login their twitter account on my site and upload a badge that would then be reflected on their actual twitter profile...on the twitter.com domain. I heard their were some issues with having users login on other sites with Twitter not liking and it possibly being a security risk, but I wouldn't actually store any logins or passwords. They would have to login that one time to get that badge and thats it.

Answer (score 5):

Start reading from 
https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in
There is more info at 
https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing

Follow the create new app link on this page

Comment: Both links are currently broken!